# How do I separate and add class to second value within ruby interpolation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am trying to give the second part of a string that has values concatenated using interpolation a class to style it. I want to be able to style the #{start} area.

The line of code I have currently is:

```
<%= link_to "#{schedule.event.name} - #{start}", devx.calendar_event_schedule_path(@calendar, schedule.event, schedule) %>
```

I have been doing some research, and from what I have found, I should be able to use single quotes for the entire string and put my erb within double quotes and have the actual values print out, like so:

```
<%= link_to '"#{schedule.event.name}" - "#{start}"', devx.calendar_event_schedule_path(@calendar, schedule.event, schedule) %>
```

However, this is not working properly. It is printing out the entire line as a string instead of the values within both #{}. I am looking on some guidance for this, as I haven't been able to find an answer during my research.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: You can try opening your `link_to` and editing the content inside as you want:

```
<style>
  .styled { font-weight: bold; color: red; }
</style>

<%= link_to devx.calendar_event_schedule_path(@calendar, schedule.event, schedule) do %>
  <span> <!-- non-styled -->
    <%= schedule.event.name %>
  </span> 
  <span class="styled">
    <%= start %>
  </span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I made an error in my post. I pasted the wrong line of original code, but have edited my question. Your answer is my original code, but I want to be able to add a class only to the #{start}, and not the entire line.

Comment: Do you want to style the `link_to`? Or do you want to style the content inside the `a` tag that `link_to` prints?

Comment: I want to be able to style the second value, not the first. I want the string printed out, but I want the #{start} to have styling by itself, such as bold, different color, etc, while keeping the entire string a link.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is printing the literal string `'"#{schedule.event.name}" - "#{start}"'` is that you are surrounding it with single quotes. Single quoted strings are not interpolated in Ruby.

However the simplest way to create the text with  tags for styling is to pass a block to `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to devx.calendar_event_schedule_path(@calendar, schedule.event, schedule) do %>
  <%= schedule.event.name %> <span class="some-class"><%= start %></span>
<% end %>
```